# Why can't I lower my API any lower than 5.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a mistake and want to lower the API to 4.4 at least.  I was able to move backwards to 5.1 but I would like to use an earlier API.  Is there a way I can access lower API's?  Below is a screenshot of the issue.

[image: Screenshot of limited Flavors]

Comment: because you dont have that SDk downloaded from the SDk manager

Comment: You probably need to install it? Use the SDK Manager or tell us what the actual problem is with 5.1

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

Comment: Basically the only problem with 5.1 that it limits the number of devices that can use this program.

Comment: Downloading the SDk using the SDk manager solved the issue.  If one of you wants to post it as an answer I'll mark it correct so you can have some sweet sweet reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try . change the `minSdkVersion` to 19 in your `build.gradle` file.you don't need to have the downloaded platform to provide backward support though your project will be complied with the version of platform you have in your sdk

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... It makes no sense to download an SDK just to set minSDKVersion... Just need to manually edit build.gradle.

Comment: i am completely agree with you Mr.Guilherme P .why spending precious MB's and GB when you can save them for later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download those SKDs in SDK Manager first.

To do this, go to **File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK**

Choose SDKs you need and press **Apply**.